# Glibc detected malloc() memory corruption (0xb6179bb8) when calling new keyword C++

Tags: c++, c, glibc

My program runs to a point where calling the **new** keyword would cause the error stated above. i.e. `char* a = new char[100]`. The error is reproducible and every time. I run the program until that point of calling the **new** keyword. It seems to be the memory location is corrupted at the point, but I'm not sure what he issue is.

What are the possible causes for this error?

Comment: The cause of the error is that you are doing something incorrect in your code.  Since you haven't posted any code, it's impossible to be any more specific than that.

Comment: look at the previous memory allocation in your code, may be something wrong with that. Or you might corrupt the heap writing to the inappropriate address before your allocation.

Comment: 0xb6179bb8 was it...?  Just let me look that one up in my Big Book of Errors.  More seriously - it's most likely to be another error with heap memory usage: deleting/freeing memory multiple times, mismatching single-var and array new/delete, overwriting memory before or after the memory blocks you've been reserving, but could be any other kind of behaviour that can cause undefined behaviour.  You can typically use tools like valgrind or purify to find the point where you make some illegal operation causing this....

Answer (score 10):

This error means that you have corrupted the bookkeeping data of the system memory manager.
Such corruptions are typically the result of incorrect use of pointers, such as

- Using an uninitialised pointer
- Using a pointer after the memory it refers to has been freed (the freeing could have happened through another pointer)
- Writing outside your array bounds